# How to check if value already exists in the data received from api before inserting it into db

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, async-await, crud

I am having hard times trying to write data received from a api to db.
I successfully got data and then have to write it to db. The point is to check whether the quote is already exists in my collection.
The problem I am dealing with is that every value gets inserted in my collection, not regarding if it exists or not.

```
 const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

 const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost/kanye_quotes'

 async function connectToDb() {
      const client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true })
      await client.connect()
      db = client.db()
 }

 async function addQuote(data) {
 await connectToDb()
 try {
    const collection = db.collection('quotes')
    let quotes = [];
    quotes = await collection.find({}).toArray()

    if (quotes = []) { // I added this piece of code because if not check for [], no values will be inserted
        collection.insertOne(data, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return
            }
            console.log(result.insertedId);
            return
        })
    }

    quotes.forEach(quote => {
        if (quote.quote !== data.quote) { // I compare received data with data in collection, it actually works fine(the comparison works as it supposed to)

            collection.insertOne(data, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return
                }
                console.log(result.insertedId);
            })
        } else console.log('repeated value found'); // repeated value gets inserted. Why?
    })
 }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it's probably better to set `unique: true` [indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on your schema. That way you won't have duplicated values.